ImageGallery игнорирование анимация на slideDuration
Я использовал в своем проекте библиотеку ImageGallery, и все работает хорошо, хотя есть одна неприятная вещь. Если я хочу быстро перемещаться между изображениями в компоненте, мне нужно подождать image_count*each_image_slideDuration. Можно ли игнорировать анимацию слайдаDuration (не удалять ее), поэтому, если пользователь хочет быстро перемещаться между изображениями, ему не нужно ждать, когда анимация закончится, чтобы одно изображение перешло в другое.
Теперь я могу справиться с завершением и запуском анимации, возможно, это поможет:
                  <ImageGallery
                    startIndex={this.state.currentFileIndex}
                    stopPropagation={false}
                    useBrowserFullscreen={false}
                    showThumbnails={showThumbnails && !isMobile && files.length > 1}
                    renderThumbInner={(data) => {
                        const { isVideo, original, thumbnail } = data;
                        if (!isVideo || thumbnail) {
                            return (
                                <div className="image-gallery-thumbnail-inner">
                                    <img
                                        className="image-gallery-thumbnail-image"
                                        src={thumbnail || original}
                                        alt={SeoConfig(pp, ATTRIBUTE.alt)}
                                        title={SeoConfig(pp, ATTRIBUTE.imgTitle)}
                                        loading="lazy"
                                        height="56"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            );
                        }
                        return (
                            <div className="image-gallery-thumbnail-inner">
                                <video width="128" height="98">
                                    <source src={original} type="video/webm" />
                                    <source src={original} type="video/mp4" />
                                </video>
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                    items={files}
                    onSlide={(currentIndex) => {
                        this.handleFileSwitch(currentIndex);
                        console.log(`Animation ${this.imageGallery.slideDuration}ms`);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            console.log('Animation is done');
                        }, this.imageGallery.slideDuration);
                    }}
                    onBeforeSlide={() => {
                        console.log('Animation started');
                    }}
                    disableSwipe={isMobile && isPanorama}
                    slideInterval={2000}
                    slideDuration={380}
                    onScreenChange={this.toggleFullScreen}
                    showNav={!isMobile || (isMobile && isPanorama)}
                    onClick={this.handleFullScreen}
                    ref={(ref) => {
                        this.imageGallery = ref;
                    }}
                />

Игнорировать анимацию я хочу и на мобильном телефоне (при свайпе), и при скольжении со стрелками (showNav props)
